# Airflow: Rscript: command not found even though Docker image has R installed

Tags: r, docker, kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

so I have a bit of an issue where I'm receiving the error **Rscript: command not found** even though there was a succesful build of a Docker image involving R.

**Issue:** Rscript: command not found while r-base-core included in DockerFile, referenced by KuberenetesPodOperator in Airflow managed by Composer

```
[2023-11-02, 01:15:40 UTC] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2023-11-02, 01:15:40 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/usr/bin/bash', '-c', 'Rscript GCS_PATH_TO_R_FILE/prueba-bash.r']
[2023-11-02, 01:15:41 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-11-02, 01:15:41 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /usr/bin/bash: Rscript: command not found
[2023-11-02, 01:15:41 UTC] {subprocess.py:97} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
```

My **Dockerfile** is the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
    r-base r-base-core r-cran-randomforest \
    libinput-dev libgbm-dev liblzma-dev libbz2-dev libicu-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev \
    python3.6 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev&& \
   rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools>51

RUN python3 -m pip install rpy2

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('data.table')"

COPY . /app
```

And my **DAG** is the following, I'm new to the KubernetesPodOperator so from what I read in the documentation, to make the BashOperatorTask run in the image cited by the K8PodOperator, they should share the same task_id:

```
from airflow import models
#from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import os 

# Get current directory
cwd = os.getcwd()
#sudo apt-get install r-base-core

default_dag_args = {
    # https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 31),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'prueba-bash-gcs',
    default_args=default_dag_args,
    schedule_interval=None,  # Intervalo de corrida de DAG (periodicidad de corrida)
)


kubernetes_min_pod = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="test-bash-r",
    #dag = dag,
    name="test-bash-r",
    cmds=["echo"],
    namespace="default",
    image="gcr.io/ldp-data-wyscout/ambienterypython:v1",
)

test_bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='test-bash-r',
    dag = dag,
    bash_command = f'Rscript GCS_PATH_TO_R_FILE/prueba-bash.r'
    )
```

Comment: Try to simplify with smaller setups. We `which Rscript` tells us it is there, so one possibility would be that the setup masks the $PATH somehow?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Do you mean I should verify the Path that the DAG takes?

Comment: When I have troubles with 'compound' operations I sometimes try to reassert that 'simple things are still simple and work'.  So say launch to do `Rscript -e 'cat(2+2)'` and check for four.  We know `Rscript` runs in `docker`.  What we do not know is what gets in the way in your case.  So I would bisect.

Comment: I'm a bit new to bash so I think I may have written what you said incorrectly, but here was the result:

I changed the bash to what I thought you meant
`bash_command = 'Rscript -e cat(2+2)'
`
`[2023-11-02, 17:56:42 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/usr/bin/bash', '-c', 'Rscript -e cat(2+2)']
[2023-11-02, 17:56:42 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-11-02, 17:56:42 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[2023-11-02, 17:56:42 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `Rscript -e cat(2+2)'`

Comment: I'm having an issue with the formatting because precisely the error uses the character for code here in stack and I'm not sure how to escape it.

The syntax error is unexpected token `('

Comment: That not legible in a comment.  Can you edit your question?  In any even it seems to end on 'syntax error' which suggests the ball is your court.

Comment: Sorry, like I mentioned in the other comment, the character making the format odd is the code format character here in Stack.

Comment: To save us another formatting issue, I passed the following 
bash_command = 'Rscript -e \'a <- 3+3;cat(a, "\n")\'' 
I received the same Rscript not found error

Comment: (BTW You can use double inside single quotes: `Rscript -e 'a <- 21; cat(a + a, "\n")'`.)  Well you now have a prodicible example for your problem.  You need to look into your setup to see why the known-to-exist `Rscript` binary from the `r-base-core` package (for which I am the Debian maintainer and hence behind the Ubuntu build too) "disappears" in your deployment.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Yes see that was sort of my original question, if there was something wrong with the kubernetes pod operator that was making the bash operator not reference the image correctly. Maybe the task id or some other sort of association.